# HashMap destroys encoding?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I've to admit that I'm not really an expert with encoding stuff etc. I've the following problem: my program has to read an text file which contains not only std. ASCII but "special chars  and languages" like `"..офіціалнов назвов Російска.."` So let's assume that this is the content of the file: `офіціалнов назвов Російска`

Now I'd like to split the whole file content in single words and create another file which list all these words in lines like:

- `офіціалнов`
- `назвов`
- `Російска`

My problem is: if I put these single words into an HashMap and read the values from it -> the encoding is lost. This is my code:

```
    final StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer(1000);
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("fileIn.txt"));

    char[] buf = new char[1024];
    int numRead = 0;
    while ((numRead = reader.read(buf)) != -1)
    {
        final String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, numRead);
        fileData.append(readData);
        buf = new char[1024];
    }
    reader.close();
    String mergedContent = fileData.toString();


    mergedContent = mergedContent.replaceAll("\\<.*?>", " ");
    mergedContent = mergedContent.replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", " ");

    final BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream("fileOut.txt")));

    final HashMap<String, String> wordsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    final String test[] = mergedContent.split(" ");


    for (final String string : test)
    {

        wordsMap.put(string, string);
    }

    for (final String string : wordsMap.values())
    {
        out.write(string + "\n");
    }


    out.close();
```

This snippet destroys the encodig. The funny thing is: if I don't put the values into the HashMap but store them immediately into the output file like:

```
...
        for (final String string : test)
        {
                        out.write(string + "\n");
            //wordsMap.put(string, string);
        }

        //for (final String string : wordsMap.values())
        //{
        //  out.write(string + "\n");
        //}


        out.close();
```

...then it works like I expect.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It seems extremely unlikely that the HashMap has anything to do with it. In general, you should specify an encoding when creating your FileReaders and OutputStreamWriters.

Comment: Why are you using a HashMap instead of a HashSet?

Comment: `FileReader` always assumes the default encoding. It's javadoc advises to use `InputStreamReader` if you don't want that (and you usually don't want it)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8")` and then the same thing with the output. And make sure your file is encoded in UTF-8

The hashmap can't possibly make anything to the encoding.

Comment: Or, if the file is not UTF-8, specify that encoding to the InputStreamReader. And the same reasoning goes for the OutputStreamWriter.

Comment: I would add that anytime you read a char you need to specify encoding or it will use the default one

Comment: Thanks a lot Bozho!

THe problem was that the file encoding was UTF-16 ..however, specifing the Inout/OutputStream reader/writer encoding works like a charm

Comment: File must be UTF-8, that's the key to my problem. Thanks m8.